# How to get Only one acadobject by selection set

Tags: c#, autocad

I have some trouble to select the targeted `acadObject`. I get the input via `selectionset.SelectonScreen` method.

Here i can get more number of object from modelspace based on my filter condition.But i need only one object from the user.

Here i mentioned my code below:

```
AcadSelectionSet selset= null;
selset=currDoc.selectionset.add("Selset");
short[] ftype=new short[1];
object[] fdata=new object[1];
ftype[0]=2;//for select the blockreference
fdata[0]=blkname;
selset.selectOnScreen ftype,fdata;  // Here i can select any no. of blocks according to filter value but i need only one block reference.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: A simple way is doing `if count > 1, show message and select again`.

Answer (score 2):

this is a direct quote from autocad developer help

http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-CBECEDCF-3B4E-4DF3-99A0-47103D10DADD.htm,topicNumber=d30e724932

There is tons of documentation the AutoCAD .NET API.

you will need to have

`[assembly: CommandClass(typeof(namespace.class))]`

above your namespace if you want to be able to invoke this command from the command line after you `NetLoad` the .dll, if it is a classLibrary.

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;

[CommandMethod("SelectObjectsOnscreen")]
public static void SelectObjectsOnscreen()
{
  // Get the current document and database
  Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
  Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;

  // Start a transaction
  using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
      // Request for objects to be selected in the drawing area
      PromptSelectionResult acSSPrompt = acDoc.Editor.GetSelection();

      // If the prompt status is OK, objects were selected
      if (acSSPrompt.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
      {
          SelectionSet acSSet = acSSPrompt.Value;

          // Step through the objects in the selection set
          foreach (SelectedObject acSSObj in acSSet)
          {
              // Check to make sure a valid SelectedObject object was returned
              if (acSSObj != null)
              {
                  // Open the selected object for write
                  Entity acEnt = acTrans.GetObject(acSSObj.ObjectId,
                                                   OpenMode.ForWrite) as Entity;

                  if (acEnt != null)
                  {
                      // Change the object's color to Green
                      acEnt.ColorIndex = 3;
                  }
              }
          }

          // Save the new object to the database
          acTrans.Commit();
      }

      // Dispose of the transaction
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's possible using other Autocad .NET libraries (instead of Interop library). But fortunately, one does not exclude the other.

You will need to reference the libraries containing the following namespaces:

```
using Autodesk.Autocad.ApplicationServices
using Autodesk.Autocad.EditorInput
using Autodesk.Autocad.DatabaseServices
```

(you get those downloading the Object Arx libraries for free from Autodesk):

You will need to access the `Editor` from an autocad `Document`.
By the code you've shown, you're probably working with `AcadDocument` documents.
So, to transform an `AcadDocument` into a `Document`, do this:

```
//These are extension methods and must be in a static class
//Will only work if Doc is saved at least once (has full name) - if document is new, the name will be 
public static Document GetAsAppServicesDoc(this IAcadDocument Doc)
    {
        return Application.DocumentManager.OfType<Document>().First(D => D.Name == Doc.FullOrNewName());
    }
```

---

```
 public static string FullOrNewName(this IAcadDocument Doc)
    {
        if (Doc.FullName == "")
            return Doc.Name;
        else
            return Doc.FullName;
    }
```

---

Once you've got a `Document`, get the `Editor`, and the `GetSelection(Options, Filter)`

The Options contains a property `SingleOnly` and a `SinglePickInSpace`. Setting that to `true` does what you want. (Try both to see wich works better)

```
//Seleciton options, with single selection
PromptSelectionOptions Options = new PromptSelectionOptions();
Options.SingleOnly = true;
Options.SinglePickInSpace = true;

//This is the filter for blockreferences
SelectionFilter Filter = new SelectionFilter(new TypedValue[] { new TypedValue(0, "INSERT") });


//calls the user selection
PromptSelectionResult Selection = Document.Editor.GetSelection(Options, Filter);

if (Selection.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
{
    using (Transaction Trans = Document.Database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        //This line returns the selected items
       AcadBlockReference SelectedRef = (AcadBlockReference)(Trans.GetObject(Selection.Value.OfType<SelectedObject>().First().ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead).AcadObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a clean solution, but that's the one I found. I hate working with those Arx libraries because of those transactions and complicated filters, but sometimes they work better.

Comment: Your solution is likely the best solution for the OP, however your terminology is incorrect. "ARX" is strictly native C++. The correct terminology for the managed API is "AutoCAD .NET API", and for the native C++ API it is "ObjectARX".

Comment: Good....I could never tell the difference until now. Autodesk documentations over these matters is very poor.

Comment: the interop assemblys are `Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.dll;` and `Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.Common.dll;` These are absolutely excluded from one another. The Inprocess assemblys are `AcDbMgd.dll` and `acmgd.dll`.

Comment: I meant: the use of one does not imply not using the other.
They have some connections.

Comment: thank you @Daniel - what does the SinglePickInSpace option do? The ARX reference manual very conveniently lists the property but provides no explanation :) - clarification much appreciated

Comment: Hello, @BKSpurgeon, It's been years I don't work with Autocad anymore, but I assume it prevents the user from picking lots of elements at once when you want them to pick only one element.

Answer (score 0):

A better method for selecting one entity would be to use the [GetEntity](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2024/ENU/?guid=OARX-ManagedRefGuide-__OVERLOADED_GetEntity_Autodesk_AutoCAD_EditorInput_Editor) method instead of GetSelection. Example use could be:

```
/// <summary> Prompt the user to select one object. </summary>
/// <param name="promptMessage"> Message to display before prompting the user. </param>
/// <returns> ObjectId of the selected object, ObjectId.Null if selection fails. </returns>
internal static ObjectId SelectObject(string promptMessage = "")
{
  AcDoc acDoc = AcAp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

  // Prepare objectId for returning
  ObjectId selection;

  // Prepare prompt options
  PromptEntityOptions options = new PromptEntityOptions(promptMessage)
  {
    AllowNone = false, // Do not allow empty result
  };

  // Get the selection result
  PromptEntityResult result = acDoc.Editor.GetEntity(options);

  // If selection went OK, save the result, otherwise ObjectId.Null
  if (result.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
  {
    selection = result.ObjectId;
  }
  else
  {
    acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage("\n Selection failure.");
    selection = ObjectId.Null;
  }

  // Return the selected objectId
  return selection;
}
```