# Can I filter an AutoCAD SelectionSet with the COM api?

Tags: c#, .net, com, autocad-plugin

I'm writing an external tool for AutoCAD (using the COM api) and I need to filter a SelectionSet, but I cant figure out the correct types for the "FilterType" and "FilterData" parameters.

I know it's outdated but I need to use the COM api and I can't for the life of me find any documentation. Can anyone with a bit more experience help me with this?

These are the problematic lines:

```
AcadApplication app = Marshal.GetActiveObject(AppID) as AcadApplication;
AcadSelectionSet SelectionSet = app.ActiveDocument.SelectionSets.Add(name);

int[] filterType = new int[1];
object[] filterData = new object[1];

filterType[0] = (int)DxfCode.BlockName;
filterData[0] = "T-siman";

SelectionSet.SelectOnScreen(filterType, filterData);
```

The last line returns the following exception:
System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid argument FilterType in SelectOnScreen'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept looking for a solution because I was stuck but then I found [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272173/how-to-get-only-one-acadobject-by-selection-set) and noticed this person uses an array of type "short" instead of type "int" for the "FilterType" parameter. Doing this worked for me.

My working code:

```
AcadApplication app = Marshal.GetActiveObject(AppID) as AcadApplication;
AcadSelectionSet SelectionSet = app.ActiveDocument.SelectionSets.Add(name);

short[] filterType = new short[1];
object[] filterData = new object[1];

filterType[0] = (short)DxfCode.BlockName;
filterData[0] = "T-siman";

SelectionSet.SelectOnScreen(filterType, filterData);
```